# HTTPS or HTTP based on previous records

Tags: search-results, ranking, google-ranking

I hope i'm not the wrong guy asking this in webmasters.stackexchange.com
Based on google webmaster records, in the previous month, I found improved ranking in google SERP. When I turn the website into HTTPS, I found low ranking.

Should I turn back to HTTP?

NB:
I'm in my personal projects to see if everything goes well.
I only have (about) 2 weeks left to decide this.
If in two weeks, using https, site ranking get improved, sure I will pick https. Otherwise, I would pick http.

Comment: Oh Lordie Lordie Lordie!  You are completely bass ackwards on you logic! HTTPS will rank at least the same as HTTP. Switching protocols is a disruption simply because you are removing one site and indexing another. Since both are the same both will rank at least the same. However, it will take quite a bit of time depending upon how favorably Google views your site.

Comment: I find different ranking in google webmaster. #7.3 (http) and #11,7 (https).
I'm sure too it will take quite a bit of time :D
Oh Lordie Lordie Lordie! lolz ... Is it good to activate temporarily both protocols since http got higher result :p
(I know that consistency is always true --- google says)

Comment: Also consider that both protocols should not be indexed or the whole theory falls apart. When switching protocols, people will redirect http to https. Cheers!!

Comment: Also, we get a ton of questions where people switch protocols and wonder why their traffic drops. Your question read like yet another. I am glad you have it together with a sense if humor!! It is refreshing!

Comment: Lolz, but I don't mean that ... okay, this is solved ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your 301 redirects set from http to https pages. Your ranking shouldn't go down, because you set up https. It's a clear nonsense. If that happened then there is a different reason for that drop. I'd keep https. Run site audit in screaming frog or somewhere else. Also a screenshot from your GSC would help. If you've done everything right you should start seeing some changes anywhere between 6 to 12-20 weeks after switching. Take your time.

P.S.: the only thing that comes to my mind why it could happen if it relates to https is that your site speed went down. Make sure your site isn't slow. It happens a lot since it takes more time to load the pages with https. Make sure it's optimized properly.

Comment: Yes, 301 is consistency, I've done with that. Talking about site speed, I use AMP full pages + optimize it and get 97% in GtMetrix, Besides, I use VPS and I think everything goes right properly. I'm sure it's a matter of time where google crawls my pages. Pls, check: https://hondaautoserang.com

Answer (score 1):

https includes many details you can use and adjust, so a simple https-setup might have a good or bad quality. In the worst case a https-connection is configured without certificate.
You can test your connection i.e. here (just a random search-results for "https test quality"): [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
One example for possible settings is the [content-security-policy](https://content-security-policy.com), but this is only one of many possible settings.

I don't know if or how far google is analyzing https-configuration before ranking and showing them in search-results but it's quite probable that pages with very bad or even blocking configuration (i.e. expired certificate) get a lower ranking.

I propose to test your page and if questions about configuration-details arise you should search or post corresponding questions that are more related to the each of the details, it's also important which server you're using as the solutions for apache-webserver and nginx-webserver usually are different, you might even use still another server.

Stepping back from https to http is usually a bad decision and I'd advise not to do it but better working on the quality of the connection.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=hondaautoserang.com

From the test --- Yes, I found the valid certificate for the free SSL --- Can the free SSL cause the bad? I also found that the SSL is shared SSL from site "hondaserang[dot]com". Please let me know further..

Comment: Your certificate-configuration got a B, so it's not too bad.
Nevertheless you still can spend time to get an A+.
Concentrate on the red marked lines in the report, you also can use other pages for testing, including google webdeveloper tools, there you can increase the page itself, that never has to do with the certificate but is important for ranking in the search-results.
I personally have mixed certificates too but the mix is concerning main- and sub-domains. I don't know if mixed certificates are ranking worse in your case but with letsencrypt it would be easy to get them separated.